# With Android Studio 4.1 update 'Plugin incompatible with the new build found: Firebase Services' There is a warning message

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, flutter

[image]

In the notice of the update of android studio, in red letters as above

Plugin incompatible with the new build found: Firebase Services

I get a warning as above,
I don't understand the meaning.
Does this mean that Firebase related packages will not work after updating android studio?

Should I not update android studio?
However,I think that there seems to be no option to never update android studio

I'm currently building an app using Flutter and Firebase,
but depending on the project, the version of the Firebase related package
may be different, what should I do?

Comment: Where is the Firebase team ? No explanation about this issue ? Should we update Android Studio or not ? I don't update just because of this warning..

Answer (score 1):

There is no error with my android studio. i am using on Ubuntu.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Late but answering for future help.

Android studio have plugin market place (you can find it at **File->setting->plugin**). Whenever android studio plans to release an update, it gives beta release first. Meanwhile, most of the plugins, update their plugin accordingly.

In your case, you are facing a warning because Firebase Services plugin had not ready the update for the time being, but in some cases, the plugins release their updates which will be available after you update the android studio. So it is safe to update to the latest android studio.

If you still facing plugin incompatibility warning, disable the plugin until the update will live. It happens only if you are using the low rated plugin. Sometimes, incompatibility warning also appears if your android cache become mess for the system. So cleaning the cache from **C:\Users\username\AppData** will resolve the issue. Or you can also choose to remove the old android studio files while updating the android studio. But there might be cases that your system do not remove files completely, so remove them manually.